# Combining dict in super class's init and subclass's init automatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, superclass

I'm creating an event system which uses the following class for events:

```
class Event(set):
    def __init__(self, name, iterable=()):
        super().__init__(iterable)
        self.name = name

    def __iadd__(self, listener):
        self.add(listener)
        return self

    def __isub__(self, listener):
        self.remove(listener)
        return self

    def fire(self, **eargs):
        for listener in self:
            listener(**eargs)
```

Now I'm trying to create some kind of a dict that would automatically create the events in its `__init__` like so:

```
class EventDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, prefix, *event_names):
        super().__init__({
            name: Event('%s.%s' % (prefix, name))
            for name in event_names
        })
```

And here's an example of usage:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
        self.events = EventDict('Player', 'change_name')

    @property
    def name(self):
        returns self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        old_name = self.name
        self.name = value
        self.events['change_name'].fire(player=self, old_name=old_name)
```

Now the problem I'm facing is subclassing.
If I were to subclass my `Player` class to include also `health` attribute, I can't use the same way of creating an event dict, cause it would override the existing one and I couldn't access `change_name` anymore.

So I'm trying to find a way where I can just do something like this (ideal solution):

```
class Player:
    events = EventDict('Player', 'change_name')

class Player2(Player):
    events = EventDict('Player2', 'attack', 'kill')

p2 = Player2()
p2.events['change_name'] += my_event_listener  # Still access Player class's events
```

Would something like this be possible?

---

I know I can do:

```
class Player2(Player):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.events.update(...)
```

But it's not the same :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop using `EventDict`.
The class itself has its own dict which supports inheritance like that.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
        self.change_name_event = Event('Player.change_name')

class Player2(Player):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.attack_event = Event('Player2.attack')
        self.kill_event = Event('Player2.kill')
```

All the events from the subclasses will be added no matter what.

I noticed that maybe you wanted to make it obvious that they're events, so I added 'event' to the names of the fields, but you don't need to if you don't want to.

If you wanted it so that the prefix is the same throughout, then you'd change the strings from something like `'Player.change_name'` to `self.__class__.__name__ + '.change_name'`. That way, it always gets whatever the *actual* class for the object is. This is part of what @jonrsharpe's solution is trying to get at.

If you wanted to make it so others could add more events dynamically, they can simply do a line like `playerObj.my_new_event = Event('Player.my_new_event')` *or* you could provide a nice method in the `Player` class to make their lives easier:

```
def add_event(self, event_name):
    setattr(self, event_name, Event(self.__class__.__name__ + '.' + event_name)
```

Comment: What if I want to loop through the events? What if I WANT them to be accessible with strings, using `getattr()` doesn't sound too convincing.

Comment: Assuming you have a good use case for looping through the events, then I'd go with @jonrsharpe's solution (or a slightly modified version).  Some good modifications would be to use `EVENTS = super().EVENTS + ...` instead of `EVENTS = Player.EVENTS + ...` since the mro can get pretty mixed around under certain conditions. You can also remove the `self.__class__.__name__` stuff, if you wanted to be going that route.

Comment: Or you can just get over yourself and use `self.events.update(...)` :)
There's no shame in it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe interesting... 
Well, you CAN technically get class attributes with `super()`, but I guess you need an instance to do that with...
Good to know. I hadn't tried it before, so I simply assumed it worked. If I had been using the extended `super()` call, I probably would have realized it, since you have to pass an instance in.
So, yeah, @MarkusMeskanen, ignore my comments here about changing to use `super()`.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you want is:

```
class Player:

    EVENTS = ('change_name',)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
        self.events = EventDict(
            self.__class__.__name__, 
            *self.EVENTS,
        )

    ...
```

Then all you need in `Player2` is:

```
class Player2(Player):

    EVENTS = Player.EVENTS + ('attack', 'kill')
```

and the inherited `__init__` will work fine.

Comment: Note this will result in an entry `Player.attack` in the EventDict, whereas I think the questioner wants `Player2.attack`. To fix this you'd have to remove the constraint on `EventDict`, that every event created by the constructor has the same prefix.

Comment: @SteveJessop I don't think it will - when `Player.__init__` is called from a `Player2` instance `self.__class__.__name__` is `'Player2'`.

Comment: yes, I had it the wrong way around. It will result in an entry named `Player2.change_name` when I think the questioner wants `Player.change_name`. Of course we don't know what `Event.name` is used for, it might not matter at all, I just mean to point out that if it does matter than `EventDict` needs to change (or the questioner must resort to adding events after the `EventDict` is created).